# index.php file keeps redirecting to a non-existent index.html file?

Tags: php, redirect

Every time I try and visit the index.php file on my website, it automatically redirects me to an index.html page. I have no redirects in .htaccess. My wordpress site is in a subdomain, but it redirects me to the main domain every time.
How can I get rid of this redirect?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included more information about your problem, we aren't all psychic. :) Could you describe your root directory? and the path of your domain? I suspect it's probably an incorrectly configured domain path.

Comment: Sorry I’m quite new to Wordpress. The Wordpress site  is stored in a subdomain (projects.donnellysurveyors.com), and the main website is donnellysurveyors.com/index.php. I have no idea why it redirects to donnellysurveyors.com/index.html, which is outside of the subdomain. Hopefully this is enough info ! Thanks.

Comment: So, to clarify when you visit projects.donnellysurveyors.com it redirects you to donnellysurveyors.com/index.php? If so there are a couple of reasons this may be happening. Firstly, Check that your subdomain isn't pointing to donnellysurveyors.com. (Remember to clear your broswer cache when making changes cmd/ctrl + refresh > Hard Reload.) Secondly, check that your phpmyadmin is pointing to the correct site domain url. If your unsure on this your hosting provider might be able to help. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried all of the above, and it finally worked. I think a few links in phpMyAdmin were wrong. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

"Redirect" from index.php to index.html might be caused by your **apache settings**. If you have index.html before index.php in your apache config file and you have both of these files in your folder, it will go for the index.html.

Try to add this to your .htaccess file (index.php preferred over index.html)

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

or change it in your **apache config file**. On Mac:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

and look for DirectoryIndex.